# "Cannot connect to server" while installing ipa through OTA

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode6, ota

I have provisioning profile is installed and successfully created the ipa. The ipa will install in Dropbox without any problem, but the same ipa will give the error while installing through OTA.

I have attached the screenshot of the error.

How can i solve the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: did you fix it? http://portal.athens.biz?

Comment: This is somehow related to SSH, but I can't get it to work. I have struggled for hours with this. I even went out and bought an SSL Cert.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may depend on what OTA server you are using.

If you are running your own OTA server, like I am, then the problem may be your URL.

I saw the exact same "Cannot connect to..." error today with my personal OTA server.  The problem was with the `itms-services` URL.

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://3ea1be94.ngrok.com/TestApp.plist
```

The `.plist` file name and the hostname for my `&url=` parameter were incorrect.  Once I fixed them and refreshed the page, everything was fine.

If you are using your own OTA server, check that the `&url=` paramter is accurate and make sure it is using HTTPS.  If you are not running your own OTA server, check with whoever is running it as they may be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

To proper distribute the IPA file from HTTP you should put a webpage with a Link  pointing the **itms-services** special link for example:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://yourdomain.com/path/Manifest.plist">Download App</a>
```

This manifest file you is very simple, you need the bundleid and the URL to the IPA file

You can find an example of start from this one: https://gist.github.com/kEpEx/777df3cb1fd4bd851409

A couple of important things to consider

- Valid certificate is required, and URL from Manifest and IPA should be HTTPS, (I'm not sure if self signed certificated works on this)
- Take care of the manifest URL, sometimes you have parameters on the URL, you want to urlencode them or use simplier url
- Sometimes you want to auth the users before allowing them to download the manifest or IPA files, take care of this, since cookies on the safari are lost when you click on this link, so if you check for session there based on the cookie you will get the "Cannot connect to" message. You will need to came out with a better aproach like generating temporaty tokens or something like that (this point took me 2 days of work to figure it out why it was failing)

Comment: I'm using a presigned url to access manifest file stored in a private bucket. I'm able to download the manifest using that url but when I use it with itms service, nothing happens. No install popup. Can there be any problem with url?